# Wall refinement of a tetraheadral Complex Geometry using Gmsh without a Geo file

Tags: mesh-generation, gmsh

I have an msh file, which is generated from a third party software(Pointwise). The geometry is a complex cylindrical pipe like structure with lot of branches. I need to refine the mesh further only on the wall region alone. How can i do this, without an .GEO file for the corresponding mesh. ( The GEO file is also very difficult to generate given the complex nature of the mesh).

Comment: So to understand better, this is a complex unstructured volume mesh and you want to refine only on the surface and update the volume mesh?

Comment: Yes, refine only the cells, which are very close to the surface not the entire volume